# Select Option keeps on displaying same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Help, every time I change or select another teacher my option keeps on displaying the same value. (value of the first selected).

```js
function updateteacher(sched_id) {

  var teach_id = $('#selteacher option:selected').val();

  alert(teach_id);
}
```

```html
$teach = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teachers"); 
echo '<td><select class="get_sched" id="selteacher" onchange="updateteacher('.$sched_id.')">
    <option value=0>Select Teacher</option>'; while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($teach)){ 
    extract($row); 
    echo '<option value='.$teach_id.'>'.$teach_fname.' '.$teach_mname.' '.$teach_lname.'</option>'; } 
 echo '</select></td>';
```

Comment: already did that and this "alert(sched_id+' '+teach_id);" the sched_id changes its value every time I choose a teacher, but the teach_id doesn't, it keeps giving me the same value (teacher_id) of the first teacher that I click.

Comment: I made you a snippet before which was a [mcve]. You broke it with the PHP, Please update your example with proper HTML. This is not a PHP issue but a jQuery one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not passing what you need. You have an ID on the select of selteacher but pass whatever is in $sched_id - if that happens to be selteacher then it is not clear in your question

Do this instead - it will work on any number of selects as long as they have `class="get_sched"` :

```js
$(".get_sched").on("change",function() {
  console.log("'Select ID': ",this.id,
              "\n'teach id': ",this.value,
              "\n'Teacher name:' ",$("option:selected",this).text()
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_sched" id="teach1">
  <option value="0">Select Teacher</option>
  <option value="1">Erza Red Scarlet</option>
  <option value="2">Regin Jude Bayer</option>
  <option value="3">Mark Mar Mendoza</option>
  <option value="4">Mackoy Koi Morales</option>
</select>

<select class="get_sched" id="teach2">
  <option value="0">Select Teacher</option>
  <option value="1">Black Scarlet</option>
  <option value="2">Bla Bayer</option>
  <option value="3">MarkyMark Mendoza</option>
  <option value="4">Sean Morales</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $teach = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teachers");
  echo '<td><select class="get_sched" id="selteacher" onchange="updateteacher('.$sched_id.')" >
     <option value=0>Select Teacher</option>

  ';
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($teach)){
   extract($row);
   echo '<option value='.$teach_id.'>'.$teach_fname.' '.$teach_mname.' '.$teach_lname.'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select></td>';

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. But I didn't down vote the answer, It wasn't me.